# Unable to write data to the transport connection: Broken pipe

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, websocket

I'm trying custom WebSocketServer using System.Net.Sockets. It's received by NetworkStream.BeginRead, NetworkStream.EndRead. Im think socket is not disconnected.
Client send message to Server. Server send to another client. And Server send to first client.

Why Writing is Failed? Pipe is network stream pipe?

Code is as follows:

```
    private void SendData(byte[] data, PayloadDataType opcode)
    {
        byte[] sendData;
        BitArray firstByte = new(new bool[] {
                // opcode
                opcode == PayloadDataType.Text || opcode == PayloadDataType.Ping,
                opcode == PayloadDataType.Binary || opcode == PayloadDataType.Pong,
                false,
                opcode == PayloadDataType.ConnectionClose || opcode == PayloadDataType.Ping
                    || opcode == PayloadDataType.Pong,
                false,  //Reserved bit 3
                false,  //Reserved bit 2
                false,  //Reserved bit 1
                true,   //Final bit
            });

        if (data.Length < 126)
        {
            sendData = new byte[data.Length + 2];
            firstByte.CopyTo(sendData, 0);
            sendData[1] = (byte)data.Length;    
            data.CopyTo(sendData, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            sendData = new byte[data.Length + 4];
            firstByte.CopyTo(sendData, 0);
            sendData[1] = 126;
            var lengthData = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)data.Length);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                Array.Reverse(lengthData);
            }

            Array.Copy(lengthData, 0, sendData, 2, 2);
            data.CopyTo(sendData, 4);
        }

        NetworkStream? stream = null;
        stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
        if (stream is null)
        {
            Logger.Error($"stream is null ??. [{GetIDAndHash()}]");
            return;
        }
        string? log;
        if (stream.CanWrite)
        {
            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
            LastTransferPacket = DateTime.Now;
            log = $"send completed, length: {sendData.Length}, sendData: {Environment.NewLine}";
            log += $"------------------------------------{Environment.NewLine}";
            log += $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sendData)}{Environment.NewLine}";
            log += $"------------------------------------{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
        else
        {
            log = $"It's a not writable. {GetIDAndHash()}";
        }
        
        Logger.Info(log);
    }
```

Comment: "Broken pipe" means you attempt to write using a connection that have been closed by the other end.

Comment: Is the connection completing?  Trying to write to a connection that did  not complete would give an error.